# Understanding matrix representation of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$ with ordered basis $B$. If $F:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear mapping then $M_B^B(F)$ is called the matrix representation of $F$ with respect to $B$.

Does this definition mean $F(v)=M_B^B(F)v$ for all $v\in V$?

Comment: Yes, the definition means that. That $B$ in the subscript corresponds to the basis in the domain, whereas the other corresponds to the basis in the codomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the expression $M_B^B(F) v$ is not defined in general, as $M_B^B(F)$ is a matrix in $M(n, K)$ and $V$ is an abstract vector space (here, we assume that $n := \dim V$ is finite).

The appropriate statement is this: The basis $B$ determines vector representations $[w]_B \in K^n$ of vectors $w \in V$, in which case we have the matrix equation
$$[F(v)]_B = M_B^B(F) [v]_B$$
(for all $v \in V$). In fact, you can think of our conventions as being true exactly so that this is true (or rather the generalization of this to general linear maps $V \to W$ between f.d. vector spaces).

In this notation, we often write the matrix representation of $F$ w.r.t. $B$ using the 'functorial' notation $[F]_B$, giving the pleasing equation
$$[F(v)]_B = [F]_B [v]_B .$$

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $M_B^B(F)$ is chosen precisely so that, if you write $v$ in the basis $B$, then the coordinates of $Fv$ in the basis $B$ are $M_B^B(F)\,v_B$.